# Google Sign In for AWS EC2 Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, amazon-ec2, google-api, google-oauth

Is it possible to allow for google sign in using an EC2 Instance. In my current application, I have google sign in enabled for localhost.

[image]

I am hosting my site on an AWS EC2 instance and am unsure what to put for the authorized javascript origins and redirect URIs. I would appreciate any help. I am using the IPV4 to access the site at the moment (http://x.xx.xx.xxx/path/to/project).

Comment: **Side-note:** An Amazon EC2 instance is just a virtual computer running an operating system of your choice. Your configuration would be unrelated to the fact that it is running on an Amazon EC2 instance.

Comment: If I try to access the webapp on the aws instance it gives me a "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()" error for the oauth stuff. Sorry, I'm just a little new to how this networking stuff works.